# How can I see where my embassies are deployed in stellaris?

Tags: stellaris

I have deployed too many embassies and need to recall one to convince my puny neighbors to be my vassals. I don't remember where they all are. How can I see where my embassies are deployed so that I can recall one.

If you click on the empire icon on another empire's planet it brings up a diplomacy screen that lists who they have embassies established with. Doing the same thing on my planets doesn't open that screen, and the equivalent of that screen for my empire isn't in Government, Empire, or Contacts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to contacts - empires and select your own empire.

Hovering over the icon containing a building and two flags (either under diplomatic status on the left or in the list) tells you about all your embassies.

Additionally under diplomatic status you'll see the flags of all the empires you have embassies with and can contact one of them to recall the embassy by clicking on it.